# Find a positive integer $n$ such that there is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_n$ that is not a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I'm in trouble with this simple exercise. If we denote $\mathbb{Q}_n:=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $n$th of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, can we find a positive integer $n$ such that there is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_n$ that is not a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I don't know if this is precisely simple, I've thought a lot and nothing comes to mind. Can you give me a hand please? I'm sure hints will suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $[\mathbb{Q}_n:\mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(n)$, which tends to be even.

Comment: I don't know how to use your hint, but i'll show you the answer I've found in the last minutes.

Take $n=7$, then Gal$(Q(\omega)/Q)$ is $Z_7^*=Z_6$, take the subgroup $Z_3$ and consider its fixed field, as $Z_3$ is the Galois group of this field and $Z_3$ is not a $Z_n^*$ group, so we have the result (I think). (I've used that the Galois group of a cyclotomic extension is a $Z_n^*$ group)

Comment: The field you're building here is the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_7$.  You are correct that this field is not a cyclotomic field, but your proof of it seems flawed.  My suggestion would be, in your case, to take the fixed field under the order $2$ subgroup.  This is a cubic field.  Why can't such fields be cyclotomic?

Comment: Is it because $\varphi(n)$ is even for $n\geq 3$? (and $\varphi(n)\neq 3$ for $n=1,2$)

PS: Can you tell me if the argument for the proof I did is at least correct? Of course, I must write it with more detail, but is the general idea right?

Comment: Yes, your argument about the $\phi$ function is correct.  Unless I misunderstood: no, the argument in your first comment is not correct.  The Galois group $Z_3$ you've constructed is not a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ but over a quadratic field.

Comment: Ohh Yes, you're right, now I see. In that case, if I take the order 2 subgroup, I can take its fixed field and consider its Galois group OVER $Q$ and argue by the fundamental theorem that it is isomorphic to $Z_6/Z_2=Z_3$ and therefore my argument works again (of course, this would be just another proof to your hint).